# Are custom SELinux policy modules portable?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

If I take a policy created, say, using `audit2allow -M` and install it on multiple servers, will it work as expected or is there something special happening when the policies are created? Ideally I'd like to deploy using Ansible.

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm in the same boat as you, want to be able to reuse my custom policies on multiple machines using ansible to roll them out.  What method did you use to accomplish this?  I can't find any info on where the policy components are stored unless they're in binary format and just appended on `/etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.31` in which case, are you just using that binary?  Appreciate any additional info you could provide!

Comment: I ended up finding a boolean value to set instead. But based on @filbranden's answer, you could probably either copy the output of audit2allow and install it (using the shell module for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELinux policy modules are portable and can be copied and reused on other servers.

As long as the servers are using the same policies (versions of the same policies are ok.) For instance, if all your servers are using the "targeted" policy (which is the default on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora), then you should be fine. Some version differences might be tolerable.

Distinct policies might be incompatible with each other, since they define SELinux types (essentially labels, names), these names will be all over your policy modules, so the modules only make sense in hosts that are using the same SELinux types. Furthermore, the rules encoded in that policy module needs to make sense in context of the other rules already in the policy. So that's why you need same (or almost same) policy for this to work.

But other than that, the modules themselves use a portable format, you can easily ship them in binary format and have them loaded on other machines, without having to install the tools that build such modules in the target machines.